# AES encryption for 16 bytes

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a file using the implementation I found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx
This implementation encrypts only 16 bytes, so my question is:
Can I just use this on my whole file 16 bytes at a time? would it weaken the encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in AES functions instead: [AesCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

[Here's](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=411) an example of how to use it to encrypt a file.

Avoid writing your own cryptography routines whenever possible-- the library versions are likely to be both better optimized and more secure than alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

AES is a block cipher with a block size of 128 bits; that's why it encrypts 16 bytes at a time.

Block ciphers can be used in various [modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).  If you encrypt each group of 16 bytes separately and independently, you're using the cipher in [ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29), which is the weakest mode because it doesn't hide patterns in the plaintext.  It'd be better to encrypt your file in a mode that produces different ciphertext for multiple occurrences of the same plaintext, such as [CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29), so that patterns in the plaintext don't translate into patterns in the ciphertext.